# how to count a frequency of a number in arraylist java without Collections.frequency

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

I'm doing and exercise for college and for some reason, the second for index is not increasing and when I the console recive a new input with a different number it doens't count.
Sorry for any grammar mistakes

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.util.*;


public class Atividade999 {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    ArrayList<Integer> valor = new ArrayList<>();

    int num2 = 0;
    int cont = 0;
    int rcont = 0;
    int num = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Informe a frequencia: "));
    for (int i = 0;i < num; i++)
      {
        num2 = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Informe o valor: "));
        valor.add(num2);
        for (int j = 0; j < num; j++){
            boolean igual = false;
            if(Objects.equals(valor.get(i), valor.get(j))){
                igual = true;
            }
            
            if(igual != false){
                cont++;
                System.out.println("Numero "+num2+" "+cont+" X");
            }
            if(igual == false){
                cont=1;
                System.out.println("Numero "+num2+" "+cont+" X");
               
            }
            break;
        }   
      }
    System.out.println("A lista completa: " + valor);
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the output when you run this program? What should the output actually be? Have you done any debugging? If not, I recommend [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for some tips to get you started.

Comment: Is the count supposed to reset to **1** if it does not match?

Answer (score 0):

Here is some pseudocode **(NOT FULL)** that may be helpful to "**count a frequency of a number in arraylist**"

```
int runningCount = 0;
for(the list of numbers)
{
    if(it is the number)
    {
        runningCount++;
    }
    System.out.println("Numero " + num2 + " " + runningCount + " X");
}
frequency = runningCount / total numbers;
```

**EDIT for clarification:** this would be in place of the giant chunk that has

```
if(it is equal) set to true;
if(it is not false) doThis;
if(it is false) doThat;
```

In fact, when you trigger the **false** condition, it currently resets the count with **cont=1**, regardless of how many there already were.